# How to use sed to update the first occurrence of some text after a specified section in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with the content:

```
#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=3000
port=3000
```

I want to update the first occurrence of "port=3000" to "port=1000" after the text "#Section2". Here is the output:

```
#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=1000
port=3000
```

Can anyone give me some hints about how to use sed for it?

Thanks

Comment: Can there be another line of text between `#Section2` and `port=3000` ?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#Section2/,/port/{s/\(port=\).*/\11000/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
sed '/#Section2/{n;s/.*/port=1000/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will search and change all `port=3000` to `port=1000` between the first occurence of `#Section2` and the next line that starts with `#`

```
sed '/^#Section2/,/^#/s/^port=3000/port=1000/'
```

Comment: OP asks to replace just the first.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '/#Section2/{f=1} f&&/port/{sub(3000,1000);f=0}1' file

#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=1000
port=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for awk, not sed. Just use awk in paragraph mode so it replaces the first `3000` in the second line of the paragraph (i.e. blank line separated block) that starts with `#Section2`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} /^#Section2/{sub(/3000/,"1000",$2)}1' file
#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=1000
port=3000
```

Want to change it in the 3rd line instead? Easy, just change `$2` above to `$3`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} /^#Section2/{sub(/3000/,"1000",$3)}1' file
#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=3000
port=1000
```

Want to change it based on the paragraph number instead of a specific string it starts with? Easy, just test for `NR` (the Number of Records/paragraphs read so far) being 1 or 2:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} NR==1{sub(/3000/,"1000",$2)}1' file
#Section1
port=1000
port=3000

#Section2
port=3000
port=3000

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} NR==2{sub(/3000/,"1000",$2)}1' file
#Section1
port=3000
port=3000

#Section2
port=1000
port=3000
```

Want to change it in the 127th line? Easy, just change `$2` to `$127`... You get the idea - whatever you want to do, it's all very easy because the tool was designed to handle requirements like this. Here's how awk sees your input file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "Record %d, Field %d of %d = <%s>\n", NR, i, NF, $i; printf "\n" }' file
Record 1, Field 1 of 3 = <#Section1>
Record 1, Field 2 of 3 = <port=3000>
Record 1, Field 3 of 3 = <port=3000>

Record 2, Field 1 of 3 = <#Section2>
Record 2, Field 2 of 3 = <port=3000>
Record 2, Field 3 of 3 = <port=3000>
```